# Windows Service open exe in foreground process

Tags: c#, user-interface, service, process, foreground

I have a Windows Service written in C # which I need to open a application (. Exe) in foreground (to display the user interface), I am using Process.Start, if I run the service from visual studio works perfectly but when I install it opens the application in the background (in the task manager process MSAMPLE) and shows no selling user, please I need your help in making this application in the foreground to display the user interface.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: So you have a Windows Service running and you want it to launch another executable to display to the user?

Comment: Which user of your computer should see this UI? What if there is more than one?

Comment: Why exactly using a service for this ? Why not a common application started when the user logon ?

Comment: A user should see the application, and you are using a service that checks whether the application was closed and run again, if you know any other way to do this also helps me (or some way to block the process of my application to not it can be terminated by the board administrator tasks)